# having problems with a div over image

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a full width card to cover my page [something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qeGUi.png) i got to achieve something like it, but its really 'buggy' as with it's responsiveness and positioning of the divs

(for example the .cardtext div not centering vertically),

i can't seem to find the solution here.. if anyone could help with the code it is below:

edit jsfiddle code: https://jsfiddle.net/whillis/Lpjxvhw1/1/

```css
.content{
     position: relative;
 }

 .card{
     width: 100%;
     padding: 0px 50px 100px 50px; 
 }

 .cardimg {
     position: relative;
     border-radius: 10px;
     top: 450px;  
     width: 60%;
     left: 40%;
 }

 .cardtext { 
     position: relative;
     top: 50%;   
     transform: translateY(-50% -50%);
     border-radius: 10px;
     background-color: white;
     color: black;
     box-shadow: 0 0px 20px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
     left: 0;
     width: 60%;
     height: 20em;
     text-align: left;
     padding: 50px 50px 0 50px;   
 }

 .btn {
     color: black;
     padding: 0.8rem;
     font-size: 14px;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     text-align: left;
     transition: 0.2s;
     border-radius: 4px;
     font-weight: 400;
     display: block;
     width: 100px;
     cursor: pointer;
     border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
     background: transparent;
 }

 .btn:hover {
     transform: scale(1.02);
     color: white;
     background-color: gray;
 }
```

```html
<div class="content">
     <div class="card">
        <img class="cardimg" src="imagens/inicio/figura1.png">
        <div class="cardtext">
           <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>
           <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In at iaculis enim.</p>
           <button class="btn card_btn">Veja mais</button>
        </div>
     </div>
     <div class="card">
        <img class="cardimg" src="imagens/inicio/figura1.png">
        <div class="cardtext">
           <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>
           <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In at iaculis enim.</p>
           <button class="btn card_btn">Veja mais</button>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Besides the " .cardtext div not centering vertically", is there any other issue to be fixed? I think the question was not really clear for me...

Comment: @BrunoMonteiro yeah that's basically it, just like make the container properly fit these content inside while keeping the layout in the same position,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of solutions, but a quick one (to not change too much your structure) it is to use `position: absolute` and tweak things around.

Here is the HTML:

```
    <div class="card">
        <img class="cardimg" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/nature">
        <div class="cardtext">
            <div class="cardtextcontainer">
              <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In at iaculis enim.</p>
              <button class="btn card_btn">Veja mais</button>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <img class="cardimg" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/city">
        <div class="cardtext">
            <div class="cardtextcontainer">
              <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In at iaculis enim.</p>
              <button class="btn card_btn">Veja mais</button>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.card {
  position: relative;
  padding: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  height: 300px; /* Change this according to your image size */
}

.cardimg {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 10px;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 55%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.cardtext {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  box-shadow: 0 0px 20px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  height: 80%;
  top: 10%;
  width: 55%;
  text-align: left;
  z-index: 2;
}

.cardtextcontainer{
    padding: 20px;
}

.btn {
  color: black;
  padding: 0.8rem;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: left;
  transition: 0.2s;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-weight: 400;
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  background: transparent;
}

.btn:hover {
  transform: scale(1.02);
  color: white;
  background-color: gray;
}
```

Please note that, depending on your image sizes, you may need to adjust things a little bit :)

Comment: it's not really what i was looking for as the image stretch, but this will help me a lot already thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome, glad that I pointed you in the right direction :)

Answer (score 1):

@Whillis I think it's because of the padding and the elements are affected by `box-sizing: content-box`

Should this be what you want? https://jsfiddle.net/sho1up6q/

Comment: i don't thinks so, it still gets the text  unaligned with the image when resizing the screen

Comment: In responsive case, you need to define certain rules and size for your images, so it will scale correspondingly as you wanted.